# Shopify preview notification other than order 9999

Tags: shopify

I am editing a client's email template for the Shipping confirmation notification.
Is there a way to preview a real order (not order 9999) when editing this template (or notification templates in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

I generally use a test order assigned to my email and trigger notifications from the order itself:

- **Resend email** button in the order timeline to trigger `Order confirmation` email
- Fulfil orders to trigger `Shipping confirmation` email
- Cancel fulfilment to trigger `Shipping update` email

This is the only way you can test data related stuff like content that changes based on line item properties, customer tags, shipping option, etc.